# Python PuLP - Variable in optimal solution out of set bounds

Tags: optimization, pulp

currently I'm setting up a batterystorage optimization problem that I solve with PuLP. I'm optimizing a lot of different scenarios and so far everything is fine (using the PuLP standard solver).

But every now and then PuLP finds an optimal solution where one of the variables (input and output of battery storage) is slightly out of the lower bound in the magnitude of <-1E7. I'd like to emphasize, that the solver status is optimal.

I initialize the variables like this:

```py
self.in_min = 0

in = [LpVariable(f"in_mwh_{i}", lowBound=self.in_min, upBound=2*self.in_max) for i in range(self.timesteps)]
```

Then in my constraints the bounds might get set tighter for separate timesteps, depending on different factors.

I really have no idea how this can happen and I haven't found any comparable problems out there. I wonder if it is possible to "accidentally" overwrite the lower bound when setting up constraints?
Or is there some sort of decimal precision on variables for the solver (that I haven't found out about)?

Thanks in advance & best regards,
frt

Solving an optimization problem, where a set of variables has the lower bound 0 and I expected the set of variables to be >= 0 in the optimal solution. But on rare occassions the variables are in the order of <-1E7, although the solver found an optimal solution.

Comment: That is probably normal.  It is just a slight bit of numerical error if the magnitude is on the order of 1e-7

Comment: Thank you, that's calming. I now started to set these values to 0, when they are <0. This now leads to a new problem: the variables of each solution will set constraints for the next solution and so on. Now the next optimization after setting the values to 0 might lead to infeasability of the problem (just as the negative values did before).Is there any technique how to handle numerical errors in PuLP?

Comment: Depends a bit on context, but if needed, you could do a tiny bit of post-processing on the result to "clean up" small deltas from zero....  `if |x| < epsilon: x = 0` or such where epsilon is maybe 1e-5